# К какому серверу обращается программа и какие запросы отправляет

Tags: сниффер

Здравствуйте, подскажите программу, с помощью которой можно узнать, куда программа отсылает запросы и какие?

Вообщем перехватить данные программы.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

> Wireshark is the world's foremost network protocol analyzer. It lets you capture and interactively browse the traffic running on a computer network. It is the de facto (and often de jure) standard across many industries and educational institutions.

Ну пошло редактирование сообщений, то я заодно переведу:

> Wireshark - наиболее известный анализатор сетевого трафика. Он позволяет перехватывать и в режиме реального времени просматривать сетевые сообщения. Wireshark де факто (и зачастую де юре) является стандартом при использовании во множестве индустрий и образовательных институтах.

Answer (score 2):

Когда то пользовался сниффером CommView, советую поглядеть и попробовать.